# Added two backgrounds in my CSS, but only one shows up

Tags: css, background

I would like to have two background images for a fansite layout I made: one background should be repeated both horizontally and vertically, the other one only vertically and needs to have a specific position. I made some search on StackOverflow and I added the following to my CSS:

```
body {background: url(images/bg.png) 162px repeat-y, url(images/bg-all.png) top repeat;}
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong though, because the only image showing up it's the second one, the bg-all.png file. I'd need the bg.png to be over bg-all.png because it's the content background. 
In order to make things clear, even though it's far from being finished (in fact, there are several other issues but I think it's better to solve one problem at a time), I'm adding a link to the test version of the layout: http://gwyneth-paltrow.org/test/

I don't know if it matters, but it's a Wordpress site.

I'm definitively not an expert and every suggestion is very much appreciated.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Please don't use tables for layout!

Comment: Oh I know, you're right! I read it on several occasions that this is wrong, but I'm turning an HTML layout into a Wordpress theme: I'm trying to do my best by searching and reading tutorials, but it's quite hard for a newbie. :(

Answer (score 1):

the second value of the background position is missing, try this and substitute the ??? with a value:

```
body {
background-image: url(images/bg.png), url(images/bg-all.png);
background-position: 162px ???, top ???;
background-repeat:repeat-y, repeat;

}
```

also note that the first declared background image is ON TOP of the second one.

http://jsfiddle.net/gB7js/

Comment: Thank you so much but, unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Here it is :)  body {
background-image:url(images/bg.png), url(images/bg-all.png);
background-position: 162px 961px, top left;
background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat;
}

Comment: the code is right,that's an html problem. probably the body is covered by some other div with some other background